# Windows 10 hangs for 5-10 seconds during normal use

Tags: windows-10, freeze, intel-graphics

Specs:

- Dell Inspiron 3531 running Windows 10 Home 64-bit (free upgrade from 8.1)
- Intel Celeron N2830 2.16 GHz, 4.00 GB RAM
- Intel HD Graphics

For a few days now, I have noticed that my laptop hangs for about 5-10 seconds at a time. If any audio/video was playing, that freezes; the cursor freezes, etc. This happens multiple times in an hour.

At the time of the freeze, I haven't been playing games, playing large video/audio files, etc.- just regular browsing and some Word files for homework.

I have updated all my drivers- including the display driver- and checked the Event Viewer for errors. For some of the occurences, it tells me the display driver crashed; for most of them it says nothing. (Seeing as I updated my display driver, I'm not sure why this is happening.) It's a problem that I could technically just ignore and deal with, seeing as it unfreezes in a few seconds, but the underlying cause might be bigger than that and I'd like to know what's going on.

Feel free to ask me for more information; I will provide is as best as I can.

EDIT: Just happened again and I got a notification in the action center: "Display driver igfx stopped responding and has successfully recovered." The screen had gone black for a second and reappeared.

Comment: More than likely the Intel Celeron N2830 cannot keep up. I would see if there is a newer video driver also.

Comment: @Moab Do you think I would I be able to find that on the Intel site or the Dell site?

Comment: I would check both for a w10 driver, install the latest version.

Comment: This version is older than the one I have installed now: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=VMX9R&fileId=3473389593&osCode=WT64A&productCode=inspiron-15-3531-laptop&languageCode=en&categoryId=VI

Comment: This is the one I have installed: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25313/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-10-and-Windows-7-8-1-15-33-?product=81071